# Is it possible to modify things in memory?

Tags: c#, c++, security, memory-management

Suppose that I have a list:
`List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();`

Then I open an URL and place every line into `myStrings`.

My question is *“hackers”* can modify my strings that I added into my list? (For example in memory?)
If yes, how can I protect against that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you trying to protect against? There is one thing if you want to keep some banking information safe and there is another if you want to keep "hackers" from modifying the HP of your game character.

Comment: Two approaches to protect against hackers are:  1) do not have your computer connected to any network, and 2) turn off the computer.  Those are not in jest.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course hackers which have access to your processes memory can read and modify your data structures in any way they like.

As how to "defend" against: No chance within the standard memory model.

There are only two options here, either keeping the hacker out of your process (not a chance if the hacker owns the system you are running on!), or try executing within one of the processor specific security enclaves, which isn't exactly easy to implement though.

In general, if your code runs (partially) on a customer's system, you must never trust that code. You must ensure by design that no sensitive data will ever end up on the customer's system, and you must always assume that input fed back to your infrastructure has been maliciously tampered with.